# Excel VBA - Type mismatch (Error 13) when copying and pasting between two work sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am tasked with copying and pasting data from one worksheet to another. The main tast is that the 131 rows from one sheet need to be copied to the other one 90 times each. Thus I have written a VBA macro. Unfortunately I have continuously received Type Mismatch Error 13.

The data looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyMultipleLines()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, h As Integer
    i = 2
    j = i
    k = 2
    
    Do While i < 11792
        If i < j + 90 Then
              Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k).copy
              Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              
              Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & k).copy
              Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("I" + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        j = j + 90
        k = k + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. According to your code, `i` never changes so your loop is infinite?

Comment: In VBA, use `&` for string concatenation. Using `+` will work as string concatenation when both operands are string, but will throw a type mismatch when one operand is a string and one is a number